# Jsf 2.2 render tbody

Tags: ajax, datatable, jsf-2.2

i have an h:dataTable with

```
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:inputText value="#{proxyUserListHandler.usernameSearch}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="username">
                    <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render=":form1:updateme" />
                    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render=":form1:updateme" />
                </h:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
```

is it possible to only render the tbody? Because when i render the whole table the input looses focus

Answer (score 0):

the only possibility i found was creating the table manually with ui:repeat and then give the tbody an id with the new html5-jsf integration

```
xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 

<tbody jsf:id="table_body">
```

now i can access it

```
<f:ajax render="table_body"
```